# Move a task to weekend in MPP 2010

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I am new to MPP. I need to move a task (say prod deployment) to a particular weekend in MPP 2010. I am planning to do the following

1. Make the particular weekends as working days for the resource which is assigned to the task
2. Going to change the start date and and date of the task to the particular weekend.

However the following microsoft URL (At the end of the  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-calendar-for-a-task-within-Project-3efc5d70-92b1-485a-ad99-2f4648b4c94f ) gives me an impression that I can make ANOTHER calendar for which the particular weekends would be working days. And this calendar can be assigned to the particular task needs to be done in the weekend. However I didn't get any option to assign another calendar for a given task.

I am really confused now.

If I compile this question out of the above two approaches can you please help me to select right answers from the below options

Option 1:  Extend working time of the assigned resource to weekend
Option 2: Create a base calendar where weekends would be as working days
Option 3: Assign the weekend base calendar to the task to be performed in the weekend
Option 4: Modify the start date and end date of the task that will be performed in the weekend.

Your expert opinion would really help me to understand the matter in more details.

Answer (score 1):

> However I didn't get any option to assign another calendar for a given task.

Please see Task Properties -> Advanced -> Calendar:

[image: Change task calendar]

Please note that in the default project you may have a 24 Hours calendar, so there is not always a need to create another calendar for that specific deployment.